# Apple's Mail showing "the identity of smtp.gmail.com cannot be verified"

Tags: gmail, certificate, apple-mail

When trying to send email using Gmail in OS X Mail, I get:

> **The identity of "smtp.gmail.com" cannot be verified.**
>
> The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be "smtp.gmail.com" which could put your confidential information at risk. Do you want to connect to the server anyway?

[image]

What to do?

Comment: This is not the first time either: https://www.seroundtable.com/archives/017825.html

Comment: And by now should be fixed: https://www.google.com/appsstatus#hl=en&v=issue&sid=1&iid=bf1b188b6295f21fbfc92d7b48dfe7be

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**[In this case](https://www.google.com/appsstatus#hl=en&v=issue&sid=1&iid=bf1b188b6295f21fbfc92d7b48dfe7be) (April 4th, 2015)** you could safely click "Connect". But in general such warnings should not be ignored. Here's how you can investigate future occurrences of such warnings:

Clicking "Show Certificate" and then selecting "Google Internet Authority G2" showed for this incident:

> **Google Internet Authority G2**
>   Intermediate certificate authority
>   Expired: Saturday 4 April 2015 17:15:55 Central European Summer Time
>   **This certificate has expired**

And for "smtp.gmail.com":

> **smtp.gmail.com**
>   Issued by: Google Internet Authority G2
>   Expires: Thursday 31 December 2015 1:00:00 Central European Standard Time
>   **This certificate has an invalid issuer**

[image] [image]

So, the certificate for Gmail was still good, but the "intermediate issuer" that was used to create it didn't last as long as Gmail's certificate. That was an error at Google's; [meanwhile](https://www.google.com/appsstatus#hl=en&v=issue&sid=1&iid=bf1b188b6295f21fbfc92d7b48dfe7be) they have installed a new certificate on smtp.gmail.com which uses a different issuer certificate. However, **as this was trusted until a few hours before the problem started in April 2015** (and assuming you used it before, when all was good), it was safe to select "Connect" then.

Comment: Well, *in principle* the fact that the intermediate is outdated means that a cautious person would no longer expect straight away that its key could not have been broken by an attacker using brute-force for a couple of years. Such an attacker *could* easily have forged the smtp.gmailcom certificate that you see. Of course the assumption that such an attacker succeeds *precisely* at th emoment o fexpiry is unfounded. Still, Google should have checked their certificate expiry schedule - encouraging users to ignore security warnings (though ok in this case) educates them into the wrong direction!

Comment: @Hagen, the certificate chain is still valid; only the dates are off. (But I've emphasized that clicking Connect is fine **today**.)

Comment: Yeah, I should have said "not trusted" instead of "invalid". Of course the process of setting expiry dates is executed with enough safety margin to allow acceptance "shortly" beyond expiry date. Then again, Google won't have to even bother adding the cert to a CRL if they happened to learn *now* that the key was explicitly compromised. Hence the CRL safety net is removed after expiry

Comment: (Very much agreed, @Hagen.)

Comment: Keep in mind that expired certificates are not listed in any CRLs (certificate revocation lists). Hence, **if** Google had previously revoked the "Google Internet Authority G2" certificate, once the certificate validity end time has passed you would no longer necessarily know about the revocation, since the revocation won't be in the CRL after that time. This is on the assumption that expired certificates are invalid anyway, so having them in the CRL would be stating the obvious.

Answer (score 9):

Google sent an email to those subscribed to alerts:

> Google Apps for Business
>
> Status: Service disruption
>
> We expect to resolve the problem affecting a majority of users of Gmail at April 4, 2015 1:00:00 PM PDT. Please note that this time frame is an estimate and may change.
>
> smtp.gmail.com is displaying an invalid certificate.
>
> April 4, 2015 11:58:00 AM PDT